# What is the best way in Angular to declare global functions to use in templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

There are two ways (or there is smth else?) to use function in templates:

**1. Declare it in $rootScope:**

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.makeURL = function (url) { 
    return 'http://mysite.ru/' + url;
  }
});
```

and in Templates:

```
<a href="makeURL('blog')">go Blog</a>
```

**2. Declate it like Directive:**

```
app.directive('makeURL', function () {
  return {
     link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var url = 'http://mysite.ru/' + $attrs.makeurl; // just example

        $element.attr('href', url);
     }
  }
}
```

and in Templates:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
  <a makeURL="blog">go Blog</a>
</div>
```

---

Or mbe i need to use Filter ? What is the best way? And can I use $rootScope for such things? or its the worst way? and why? Plz I need to understand these things.

---

**EDITED: I think this is the answer: [Angular JS - Make service globally accessible from controllers and view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571714/angular-js-make-service-globally-accessible-from-controllers-and-view)**

Comment: I would go with filter as it is a type of transformation you are doing.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete case, and not "just an example"? Here, a directive is clearly the way to go (but with a template, not by using `$attr`!), but that may not be the question you really want to ask, right?

Comment: The main question is "If we can use $rootScope for global variables its cool, but many ppl say that its bad and i cant understand why". And if its bad what way i need choose))

Comment: Ok, about example. There is provider that i use and it generates service which generate path for all urls in project, so now i use it as `app.run(function ($rootScope, getRoute) {
 $rootScope.getRoute = getRoute;
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service

```
mymodule.service('URL',function(){
 this.make=function(){...}
});

mymodule.controller($scope,URL){
$scope.URL=URL;
}

<a href="{{Url.make(somedata)}}"/>
```

A service will make you controller more testable AND you'll be able to test the service in isolation. It's more difficult if you add anything to the rootscope in the angular.run method.

Comment: Ok, but if i need function as Global it means that i need to use it in each scope where it needed? huh.. And plz explan why i need to use service instead glob declare in $rootScope ?

Comment: well you can have a global controller.And because you dont want to attach anything to the rootScope(except events).That's "bad" practice.

Comment: 'bad practice' - it's the same answer as well - 'nothing'. Sry ofc, but want to know more.. I can understand if using $rootScope to make functions as global requires more memory or smth else.. but not 'bad practice'. PS global controller is good idea i think.

Comment: using rootscope will make your controller less testable.You cant test your controller in isolation if you need to execute run before you test your controller.With a service you dont need to do anything to test you controller,that's why.If you care about testability you wont add anything to the rootscope.