# How to globally access/throw a custom error in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

I would like to create my own custom error, something like this:

```
function CustomError(message) {
   Error.captureStackTrace(this);
   this.message = message;
   this.name = "SomeCustomError";
}
CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

How should I integrate custom errors in angular? I would simply be able to throw the same custom error anywhere I am in angular, no matter if in a service, controller, or similar. I certainly wouldn't want to 'dependency inject' the CustomError each time.

```
throw CustomError('some message');
```

Or, if I am thinking about, I also could simply:

```
throw {name : "CustomError", message : "some message"};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to override the default exception handler? If so, look at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler. It seems you can also add functionality while retaining the original exception handling functionality using decorators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595469/how-to-override-exceptionhandler-implementation

Comment: No, I already did this. I just want to define my own custom errors, and I don't know how to make it globally available in angular.

Comment: Hmmm, seems like there is an option of creating and then adding the service to the rootScope so you don't have to continuously inject it in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571714/angular-js-make-service-globally-accessible-from-controllers-and-view. Though, not sure if it still meet your requirements?

Comment: Well, I actually also could append it to `$window` somewhere during my angular's bootstrap function. Just a thought, maybe not bad...

Comment: Sounds interesting. Post what your final solution ends up being.

Answer (score 1):

In my app.js - bootstrap file, I have now something like that:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .run(['$window',
        function($window) {

            function CustomError(message) {
                Error.captureStackTrace(this);
                this.message = message;
                this.name = "SomeCustomError";
            }
            CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);

            $window.CustomError = CustomError;
            // From here on, I can throw it anywhere: 
            // throw new CustomError("D'oh!");
        }
    ]);
```