# Is there any such time when making a service accessible on the $root is acceptable?

Tags: angularjs

Now, I know global variables is an anti-pattern, and perhaps more so in an Angular world than in other places... however, I have come across a use case where I'm leaning towards breaking the rule...

I have read the comments here, and strongly agree with all the posters who point out the anti-angular'ism my idea represents and the anti-pattern it generally is...
[Angular JS - Make service globally accessible from controllers and view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571714/angular-js-make-service-globally-accessible-from-controllers-and-view)

However, now for my use case, I have a $theme service which contains a lot of variables and constants, such as paths to images and strings.

We also have a framework of components which are all made accessible to application designers via directives, allowing most of our applications to be build using just our internal framework in the form of markup directives.

I could make directives for each of the needs, however it would sacrifice the flexibility of having low coupling between views and themes, by allowing developers to access the $theme service directly in the views, without having to (re)write controllers (or even create controllers for everything) or implement new directives, it would allow them to work purely in the markup made available to them by the internal framework. Basically I want to enable application designers to be able to work purely in markup.
We also have made directives which wrap references to ngResource and exposes the methods of the resource on the current $scope as well as directives which binds the current $scope to variables on the $stateParam service, etc, etc, hopefully you get the picture...

e.g.

```
<h1>{{$root.$theme.NAME}}"</h1>
<img my-src="$root.$theme.logo.url" />
```

instead of lots of code with controllers and directives...

```
<my-theme-name />
<h1 my-theme-name />
<my-theme-logo />
<img my-theme-logo />
```

The difference between these two approaches is that the ones where the directive is attached a primary tag, it's purely a decorator, where in the former cases where the directive is the primary tag, the directive template will determine the resulting primary tag. A slight difference yielding a larger degree of flexibility in the approach where we are using the directives purely as decorators and not information experts.

However, instead of having to write directives all together, perhaps for things which are purely added to the individual theme, just to be used in a single app, in which case adding support in the $theme service seems to be wrong approach...

However, going with a strict custom directive driven approach, it will possibly allow us to more easily port to e.g. Angular2 or even something else by simply building an adapter or transpiler, without having to rewrite any of the markup, but simple rewire the directives to new controllers and handlers written in the new library.

So, back to my question, provided we work around this caveat for the testing, would it be a viable approach, or is it a slippery road to global variable hell where soon we will have polluted our $root with tons of things because it was the easy way ?

#### _____ Update 7th May 2016 _____

OK, I decided against making my theme service globally available when I suddenly was compelled to put my $fileSaver service out on the global scope as well, indicating the my fears of "scope-creep" were valid, instead I decided to implement a `<my-injector my-name="$theme" />` directive which allows application designers to import services declaratively, the directive makes the injection target specified in the myName attribute available on the current scope.

It allows app designers to use the service anywhere in the scope like this:

```
<my-injector my-name="$theme" />
<img ng-src="$theme.logo.url" />
```

I thought about creating difference convenience directives, e.g. some app designers might find `<my-import my-name"$theme" />` more intuitive, but that is a different discussion...

Comment: I'm interested to see what others have to say about this. I think its the slippery road but that's just me.

Comment: what's the difference adding `<img my-src="$root.$theme.logo.url" />` over `<img my-theme-logo />`? same amount of work no? besides creating the directive, which in these cases should be small...

Comment: @Jorg Thanks for your comment, yes, well, somewhat, however in one case the resulting tag is defined by the directive template and the other the application designer decides the tag and just appends the directive as a decorator... slight difference which perhaps in the case where the directives are purely decorators, allowing the application designer to chose which tag to append the decorator to, could offer the flexibility required which would make my approach with the global $theme less demanding.

I have updated my response to include these thoughts, thanks again for your feedback...

Answer (score 1):

It's not an absolute necessity to avoid rootScope. From the [Angular FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq), with my emphasis:

> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. **In particular, don't use it for code, only data**. If you're tempted to put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.
>
> **Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.**

Since your theme seems to be largely data, I say why not use root? If it does contain functions, is it possible to split it? I can't decide that for you, I haven't seen what you're actually trying to do...

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, the $theme service basically just holds the data in the form of semi constants, that is at least what it will expose in the role it would fill on the $root, it also has a number of $providers and configuration options for various aspects of the theming, however they would not be exposed in the $root. Most would likely be possible to be done by CSS, so it's perhaps as a markup-centric alternative to CSS for application designers to have the choice between the two.

Comment: Well, that is the official answer... not sure what else you can expect. You could have a look at how angular-material have implemented their theming service perhaps.