# Global variable (Class)

Tags: angularjs

I've made a really simple class,

**user.class.js**

```
'use strict';

class User {

constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
}

getUserId() {
    return this.id;
}

}
```

and in my main controller, when someone logs in, I want to create a new instance of that class like this

```
const user = new User(2);
```

but how can I access this user from another controller?

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend you to use a **service** for such a logic. More precisely, create a **global service** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571714/angular-js-make-service-globally-accessible-from-controllers-and-view . Reference about what a service is: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services . PS: Avoid manually sharing variables through controllers, just use services since they are meant to do exactly such kind of activity. Making a global service allows you to have a two-way binded variable in each controller, which is controlled by the service. **remember to make a GLOBAL service**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For share variables in AngularJS between Controllers, you should to use [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)